# Deploying Angular2 Application - Folder Structure Changes

Tags: html, angularjs, gulp, compass-sass

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/munroAllie/HWA)

## Summary

After changing my folder structure to keep development and production separate I get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error.

### Note

When I upload my production folder contents via FTP, the site works fine. Only when local do I get the above stated error. Before changing the folder structure, my local server (gulp-connect) worked just fine.

## Issue

I an encountering the following errors:

#### Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

My application was working great and ready to launch. I had been working locally with a gulp-connect server. I wanted to create a gulp task that would minify code, copy/paste dependencies, compress image. My end goal would be to have a folder that contained only production ready files.

To do this I created the following folder structure:

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQhRu.png)

The first and biggest change was to copy/paste (using gulp) the node modules dependencies into appropriate folders. As these changed I updated my index.html to reflect to new locations of the scripts from the node_modules folder to /js.

## index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="images/HWA_Emblem.png">
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Halifax Wildlife Association</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


    <script src="js/lib/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/format-google-calendar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## systemjs.config.js

```
 /**
     * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
     * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
     */
    (function (global) {

      // map tells the System loader where to look for things
      var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',

        '@angular': '/js/lib/@angular',
        'ng2-page-scroll': '/js/lib/ng2-page-scroll.umd.js',
        'rxjs': '/js/lib/rxjs'

      };

      // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
      var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
      };

      var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router'
      ];

      // Individual files (~300 requests):
      function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
      }

      // Bundled (~40 requests):
      function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
      }

      // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
      var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

      // Add package entries for angular packages
      ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

      var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
      };

      System.config(config);

    })(this);
```

## config.rb

I use compass to compile my SASS so I then updated this accordingly:

```
    require 'compass/import-once/activate'
    require 'breakpoint'
    # Require any additional compass plugins here.

    # Set this to the root of your project when deployed:

    http_path = "/builds/development"
    css_dir = 'stylesheets'
    sass_dir = 'sass'
    images_dir = 'images'
    javascripts_dir = 'javascripts'
    sass_options = false
#tsconfig.json#
My TSConfig file had no changes

    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
      }
    }
```

## gulpfile.js

I am not done of this file just yet, it however does correctly make a production folder.

```
// Add requiements
var gulp        = require ('gulp'),
    gutil       = require ('gulp-util'),
    concat      = require ('gulp-concat'),
    browserify  = require ('gulp-browserify'),
    compass     = require ('gulp-compass'),
    connect     = require ('gulp-connect');
    sourcemaps  = require ('gulp-sourcemaps');
    typescript  = require ('gulp-typescript');
    tsConfig    = require ('./tsconfig.json');
    gulpif      = require ('gulp-if');
    uglify      = require ('gulp-uglify');

var env,
    htmlSources,
    sassSource,
    jsSources,
    appSources,
    imageSources,
    tsSources,
    depSources,
    outputDir

env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if (env==='development') {
    outputDir = 'builds/development/';
} else{
    outputDir = 'builds/production/';
}

//Setup path variables
htmlSources =   [   
                    'builds/development/partials/*.html',
                    'builds/development/index.html'
                ];

sassSources =   [
                    'builds/development/components/sass/style.scss'
                ];

jsSources   =   [ 
                    'builds/development/components/scripts/*.js'
                ];

depSources  =   [
                    'js/lib'
                ];

tsSrc       =   [
                    'builds/development/components/typescript/*.ts'
                ];
imageSources=   [
                    'builds/development/images/**/*.*'
                ];

gulp.task('CopyDep', function(){
    gulp.src('node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js').pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + depSources));
    gulp.src('node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js').pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + depSources));
    gulp.src('node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js').pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + depSources));
    gulp.src('node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js').pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + depSources));
    gulp.src('builds/development/components/scripts/format-google-calendar.js').pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + depSources));
    gulp.src('builds/development/components/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js').pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + depSources));
    gulp.src('builds/development/components/scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js').pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + depSources));
    gulp.src('builds/development/systemjs.config.js').pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', gulp.dest(outputDir)))
    gulp.src('node_modules/@angular/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'js/lib/@angular'));
    gulp.src('node_modules/ng2-page-scroll/bundles/ng2-page-scroll.umd.js').pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'js/lib'));
    gulp.src('node_modules/rxjs/**/*.*').pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'js/lib/rxjs'));


});


//Combine Javascript Files
gulp.task('js', function(){
    gulp.src(jsSources)
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'js'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});

//Process Typescript
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
  return gulp
    .src(tsSrc)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(typescript(tsConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'app'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

//Process SASS files
gulp.task('compass', function(){
    gulp.src(sassSources)
        .pipe(compass({
        config_file:    'config.rb',
        css:            'temp',
        sass:           'builds/development/components/sass'
        }))
        .on('error', gutil.log)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir + 'css'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});

//Reload HTML files if change is recorded.
gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src(htmlSources[1])
        .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', gulp.dest(outputDir)))

    gulp.src(htmlSources[0])
        .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', gulp.dest(outputDir + 'partials')))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
}); 

// Watch all sources file directorys and run tasks if changes happen.
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(jsSources,   ['js']);
    gulp.watch(sassSources, ['compass']);
    gulp.watch(htmlSources, ['html']);
    gulp.watch(tsSrc, ['typescript']);
});

// copy images in production
gulp.task('images', function(){
    gulp.src(imageSources)
        .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', gulp.dest(outputDir + 'images')))
}); 


// Start a server for project.
gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
    root : '',
    livereload : true,
    fallback: 'builds/development/index.html'
    });
});


// Run all tasks above by using default command "Gulp".
gulp.task('default', ['CopyDep', 'images', 'js', 'images', 'typescript', 'compass', 'html', 'watch', 'connect']);
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` *usually* indicates that you are serving up HTML instead of javascript when requesting a javascript resource/file. This *usually* happens when you have a SPA with a catch-all on the server to serve up the index.html when no resource is found. Since you didn't post the bit that is the "server" which serves the files, not much help can be done.

Comment: `connect     = require ('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
    root : '',
    livereload : true,
    fallback: 'builds/development/index.html'
    });
});`

This is all I have for the server. I am unsure why this issues is happening as all I did was change the folder structure. Other than the code above this is all I am using for the server.

[link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect)

Your logic makes sense as to why my production server works just fine (goDaddys)

Comment: Your fallback listed there is definitely what is being served. Perhaps `root` should be set to something else... like `'builds/development'`?

Comment: Your exactly right, once I set this to the root, it did work but I got back a very similar error.
`Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0      core.umd.js`

With a quick google it appears to be the same issue as you mentioned above. Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: not too sure, but the `packUmd` function does look like it may need some adjustments. What is the path that appears before `core.umd.js` in the network tab?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/js/lib/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js

I am currious why there is 2* '/', in the path but the file still loads.

Comment: I loads "fine" because the fallback will load no matter what. I'm guessing you don't need the leading slash in `'/bundles/'`. Also can you confirm that the file exists in your development directory, the screenshot doesn't go into the @angular directory, where this file is supposed to live.

Comment: Yes, Core.umd.js is located in the @angular folder.

Unsure why but that error I am getting is:
`Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 907`
a google search says this is related to same solution you identified but not sure how to fix this.

I sure wish there was more documentation on how to use angular in your on folder structure. Having everything in the root did't really make sense to me, perhaps there is a simple gulp tool that would have bundled everything for me?